# join more than tables in json

Tags: php, mysql, json, join

I have problem when I want to display data by json file. If I display data in one table it is ok, but when I want to join more than tables no data displayed

```
<?php
mysql_connect($hostname,$username, $password) or die ("<html><script language='JavaScript'>alert('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.'),history.go(-1)</script></html>");
mysql_select_db($dbname);

 $query = "SELECT Product.Product_Name, Product.Price, Product.Image, Gender.Description, Age.Description, Status.Availability  from Product join Age on Age.Age_ID join Gender on Gender.Gender_ID join Status on Status.ID";

$result = mysql_query($query);

//Create an array
    $json_response = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['Product_Name'] = $row['Product_Name'];
        $row_array['Price'] = $row['Price'];
        $row_array['Image'] = base64_encode($row["Image"]);
        $row_array['Description'] = $row['Description'];
        $row_array['Description'] = $row['Description'];
        $row_array['Availability'] = $row['Availability'];



        //push the values in the array
        array_push($json_response,$row_array);
    }
    echo json_encode($json_response);

    //Close the database connection
    fclose($db)
?>
```

Comment: table schema would be helpful. your join is horribly broken and can't be fixed without seeing how the tables relate to each other.

Comment: @pala_ here is the picture for the table schema                                http://www.ya-techno.com/up/uploads/1428376147411.png

Comment: can you please add http://sqlfiddle.com, so we can understand your data

Comment: @LeaTano I don't know how to use this one, can you say what should I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last join `on Status.ID` is the issue. `Status` table doesn't have `ID` column. Based on you diagram, you have `Status.Status_ID` (you don't have `Status.ID`) Also, your data have to have related data where each table has values in common, otherwise, you will get empty results

Your Diagram:

[image]

Change your Query

```
SELECT 
    Product.Product_Name,
    Product.Price,
    Product.Image,
    Gender.Description,
    Age.Description,
    Status.Availability
FROM
    Product
JOIN
    Age ON Age.Age_ID
JOIN
    Gender ON Gender.Gender_ID
JOIN
    Status ON Status.ID
```

to

```
SELECT 
    Product.Product_Name,
    Product.Price,
    Product.Image,
    Gender.Description,
    Age.Description,
    `Status`.Availability
FROM
    Product
JOIN
    Age ON Product.Age_ID = Age.Age_ID
JOIN
    Gender ON Product.Gender_ID = Gender.Gender_ID
JOIN
    `Status` ON Product.Status_ID = `Status`.Status_ID
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74645/discussion-on-answer-by-lea-tano-join-more-than-tables-in-json).